# How to add HTML to PHP else code

Tags: php, html

How can I make the "(@count new)" text in the following code display with bold formatting?

```
else {
$text = format_plural($count, '1 new',
                    'Private Messages (@count new)');
}
```

Here is the full code snippet:

```
function bootstrap_primary_privatemsg_new_block($count) {
    $count = $count['count'];
    if ($count == 0) {
        $text = t('Private Messages');
    }
else {
$text = format_plural($count, '1 new',
                    'Private Messages (@count new)');
}
return l($text, 'messages', array('attributes' => array('id' => 'privatemsg-new-link')));
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to format something bold in HTML?

Comment: 'Private Messages (<b>@count new</b>)'

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more detailed. When I add the <b></b> to the 'Private Messages (@count new)') portion of the code, the <b></b> is simply displayed on the front-end, without affecting the formatting of the text.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
$text = format_plural($count, '1 new', 'Private Messages (<strong>@count new</strong>)');
```